# How to share data between 2 android applications

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing 2 application of android parallaly.Now i want to access one application data from another application i.e the data from folder data/data/com.sampleApp1.As both application will be developed by me so is it possible to access data of one application from another application if possible please provide solutions.Thanks in advance

Comment: In a such scenario, maybe having a shared location on storage would be more appropriate? For example, having a folder that both application will write, and read from there.

Comment: You can use ContentProvider. Check this [example](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing both applications you can use Shared User Ids. Both application will share permissions and files. Please be careful and check if you need/want this.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#userid

An another option would be a ContentProvider.

Comment: I had already added sharedUserId in manifest of both application but till it is giving FileNotFoundException caused by permission denied

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to access different folder and whether it is possible or not. I think the best idea for you is to use content provider.

Check this site:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Local data you are mentioning, SQLite, is PRIVATE for application by default and it is not appropriate for sharing data between apps because of security and transparency issues. Content Providers are the tool of this trade.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Refer Standard Content Providers Training Tutorial from developer.android**
Please go through once you will not face any problem in future regarding Content provider
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html